# html hyperlink <a> with no refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, page-refresh

the a tag is used in Jquery dropdown menus and generally in ajax . But the problem
it refeshes the page . How can I force it not to refresh ?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "refresh", do you mean the link gets followed and the page gets reloaded?

Answer (score 7):

Use `e.preventDefault()` in the click handler and `return false;`.

Comment: And I didn't know about it :)  Nice to be aware of the options though.

Answer (score 6):

Just add `javascript:void(0)` in href

Example: `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a handler for the `click` event on your anchors which after doing its work (executing and processing an Ajax request) returns False. This will prevent the event from propagating and calling the default handler (which is to `GET` the resource referred to by `href`).

Comment: Thanks too much bro . Adding return false; at the end of the javascript function is the simplest way. But it does not seem to work when the script in an external file . Thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and did this to resolve.

1. Remove the `href` attribute.  Many people will set it to "#" because "it doesn't go anywhere".  Not entirely true.  It'll take you to the top of the page, which is a pain when you have a scrolling page.
2. Unfortunately, removing the href tag will remove the normal rules for your mouse pointer.
   If you want the cursor to change when someone mouses over it, style your href-less a tags with :-

cursor : pointer

If you do those two things, your a tags won't go anywhere, won't scroll the screen and will look like regular links when a user mouses over them.

Comment: Arguable.  When you think about what the a tag ( particularly with href ) is for, anything that suppresses its default behaviour is, by definition, a workaround.  What does your href tag currently contain?

Comment: Usually, the way I do these things to make a functional site without the Ajax bits and then to have a script fix up the events on all the anchors I want. The backend becomes DRYer and the frontend works even without Javascript. But then again, I've not designed *that* many websites.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well, you're to be applauded for trying to apply some degradability into the mix.  Having done the same on some projects, I do wonder whether it is worth it.

Comment: I don't think it's *worth* it. Everyone has javascript these days but I've generally felt that the entire app becomes more elegant and tight if I design it that way.

Comment: Thanks Paul . Yes it works fine but when you click it,the cursor becomes in edit mode like if it is a text .